# lvalue required as left operand of assignment, can't find issue

Tags: c

I'm new to computer programming and i'm having some problems, i need help.
Where am i doing wrong ?

```
if (x=='c' || x=='C')
{
    a*1.8-32=a;
    printf("%f", a);

}

else if (x=='f' || x=='F')
{
    (a-32)/1.8=a;
    printf("%f", a);
}

else
{
    printf("Please enter a valid format.\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I can't even imagine what you're trying to do with `a*1.8-32=a;` and `(a-32)/1.8=a;`?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` -- What is this: `a*1.8-32=a`?

Comment: [Understanding lvalues and rvalues in C and C++](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) should be very helpful.

Comment: I've tried to change the temperature to Fahrenheit if it is celcius by that formula and than print it with a, again. a=a*1.8-32 i meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write

```
a*1.8-32=a;
```

in C. the compiler tells you that the "lvalue" (left value) of an assignment needs to be actually assignable.

What you probably meant is

```
a = a * 1.8 - 32;
```